# react-native-image-crop-picker is not Working React Native in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to integrate react-native-image-crop-picker in react native to pick up multiple images at once but failed to do so.
It show me the following error:

> error: Undefined is not an object (Eveluating
>   '_react_NativeImageCropPicker2.default.openPicker

[image]

Different versions of my packages are:

```
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"expo": "^25.0.0",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-
 25.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.20.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package not able to using with expo. If you want to use this package, you create a new react native cli project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw [library's installation instructions](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#install)?

This library uses deep linking which won't be allowed in your case as you use Expo!

For now you could use another library that doesn't need linking, but I would highly recommend to use *react-native-cli* way, if you don't want to reinitialize new project, you could detach/eject the project but it is **irreversible**!. Then follow [installation instructions](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#install) and it will be fine.

Comment: thank you for your response. Is there any other alternate package for expo?